# Two dimensional string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I want to iterate the following 2d string array in C language; this is the code for iterating:

```
char list [][] ={{"dan","1"},{"sara","2"},{"loura","3"}};

for(i=0; i < 3;i++){

    for(j=0; j < 2;j++){

        if(strcmp(list[i][0],data)==0)
        {
            /*some code*/              
        }

    }//end column 


}// end row for
```

I got many warnings like "array type has incomplete element type".
I think the problem is in the 2d array. I tried other ways of initializing like:

```
 char **list[][]=......
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you actually aware what `char **list[][]` would be? Don't just do trial and error.

Comment: What do you need? What exact messages do you get and where exactly? The definition should actually report an error, not just a warning. Are the strings supposed to change or are they constant? If non-constant: you you intend to change them in the array or just change the whole entries?

Comment: Ok see, this 2d array will not change, I am using it as database point of view, I need to access them and view them in certain condition. But I have never worked with 2d arrays in c that is why I am confused

Comment: BTW the strings written in my array are not the real ones, because they are too long. I want to access the array, compare the name, if it is found I want to print the number associated with it.

Comment: `char **list[][]`, is not a pointer to a 2d array of char, instead it is **2d array of pointers which hold addresses  of pointers of chars**, you just can't initiate that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment the array will never change, you should make it constant. Also use pointers to the entries. The latter avoid the need to provide the max. size of characters per "string" and avoids waisting space:

```
const char * const list[][2] = { { "...", "..." } , ... };
```

This is a 2D array of pointers to `char`. The initialiser will set the pointers to the *string literals* given in the initialiser. This is the most comfortable (in the sense of automatic memory space sizing) you can get. The compiler can deduce the outer (leftmost!) dimension by the number of pairs in the initialiser. For the inner dimension, you have to specify. The sizes of the strings literals are not relevant for the array, as we use pointers (the data is not stored in the array itself).

The first `const` tells the compiler the object pointed to will not be modified. The second tells the same for the pointer itself (which implies the whole array will not be modified).

With this, you can use `strcmp` as you used in your question:

```
strcmp(list[i][0], data)
```

Make sure `data` is **always** properly terminated (i.e. `'\0'` at the end).

**Update:** According to your edit, you want to access the second entry as a number. Maybe an integer would then be better than a string. For this, you need a 1D array of a `struct`:

```
const struct {
    const char *name;
    int number;
} list[] = { { .name = "name", .number = 15 } , ... };
```

(The `.name =`/`.number =` parts are designated initialisers; standard since C99.)

Usage:

```
strcmp(list[i].name, data)
int my_number = list[i].number;
```

That way you may process the integer part easier and you name both entries easier. Even if you still use two strings, this might be the better approach, because you should use arrays only if all entries have the same semantics, otherwise a `struct` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AMH9: Welcome. Just think about the Updated variant. You likely will also notice it results in better readable/maintainable code;-)

Comment: What is `const * const list[][]` ?

Comment: @Alexguitar: I explained the `const`s in the text. Where is your exact problem?

Comment: The type for the list defaults to int, shouldn't it be using char instead?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SmUJ1NWg
because that's what I get when trying to compile a program with that line of code.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is it should probably be `const char * const list[][]`

Comment: @Alexguitar: Oh, thanks. Yes there was of course the type missing. Actually it should result in a compiler error without type. Only function declarators default to `int` and shall generate a compiler-warning  since C99.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare it like this

```
char list[][2][6] = {{"dan", "1"}, {"sara", "2"}, {"loura", "3"}};
```

1. It's an array of arrays of arrays of chars. So a 3D `char` array. You only had 2 pairs of `[]`.
2. You must specify all but the first dimension. It wouldn't hurt to say `char[3][2][6]` either.
3. The last size "6" is the size of the longest string `"loura"` plus the null-terminating `char`

Comment: If I do it this way, does the iteration method in my code still valid?

Comment: The C standard does not provide a type _string_. It is just convention how a sequence of `char` is interpreted as "string".

Comment: This `list[i][0]` will get only names e.g. "dan" then "sara". If that's what you want it's valid.

Comment: @Olaf yes I know, that is why I am using pointer to first char of chars sequence.

Comment: @Olaf interesting. Just searched through a draft version and the word "string" doesn't appear. Didn't know that

Comment: Well, at least "string-literal" **does** appear. Hewever, it is just a sequence of `char`s (the standard uses the phrase _character sequence_) which is `'\0'`-terminated. Interpretation is left to the handling functions - as I wrote: convention.

Answer (score 1):

`if(strcmp(list[i][0],data)==0)`

should be

```
if(strcmp(list[i],data)==0)
```

You want the address of the string, not the first element.

Comment: @ameyCU because I want to access the next element (list[i][1])if the condition is true

Comment: @AMH9 Yes , I know  that's why you need  a  3-d `char` array. And the previous comment was for the answer .

Comment: @ameyCU Yes it does:  printf("%p\n", list[0]);

Comment: Using `printf` to verify an address is a very bad idea. This because it does not show the actual type of the pointer. Also note that `printf("%p\n", list[0])` is undefined behaviour, because `printf` requires a `void *` for `%p`.

Comment: @Olaf, it's a great idea in this case because I simply wanted to show AMH9 that the syntax does resolve to an address. Also, the behavior is deterministic because an address is an address is an address regardless of what's stored there: the %p handles it just fine.

Comment: How do you even know it is an address? Whatever value is there might be show; Invoking undefined behaviour proves absolutely nothing. Even if it is an address (I did not say it is not!), you do not show it has the correct type, thus can point to anything. And no, "an address" is **not** "an address". The C standard very well differentiates between different types of addresses. Anyway, you do not answer the actual question, as the array as such is wrong. There is one dimension missing.

Comment: @Olaf, an address is an address is an address. What the address points to is always at issue, but the address format does not change. If I print the address it will print exactly the same regardless of what it points to.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson: Please provide a reference where the standard states the format of a pointer does **not** depend on its type. E.g. alignment can differ. In C an address also has a specific semantic, i.e. type of the pointed-to object. There is no guarantee the addresses of different object types at the same physical address compare equal.

Comment: @Olaf , it's axiomatic. Think about it. The standard does not address the format of an address because addresses vary between hardware platforms.

Comment: @Olaf , it's axiomatic. Think about it this way: unions would not work otherwise. The standard does not address the format of an address because addresses vary between hardware platforms. Given the same hardware the address of an int is the same as the address of a float is the same as the address of a string. What the address points to is different but the address format doesn't change. I would like to see your source for an address semantic relative to the pointed-to object.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson: Finally: A `union` is a different type than a pointer to one of its components. For example, it might require a larger alignment than one of the types of its fields to accomodate the other fields. Just repeating your mantra "an address is an address ..." does not get you further. There is only one convertible address: `char *`. And yes, there were architectures which encoded the datatype **in** a pointer. Some custom FPGA implementations might also do it. I didn't write address _semantics_ were different, but the address _encoding_ might include the semantics ....

Comment: @DelmerNicholson: ... and of course depend the semantics of an address on the type it points to. That is one part of the strict aliasing rule and the effective type in the C standard! That was just not the point here. There is a reason `printf("%p") explicitly requires a `void *`, not just an object pointer, so you actually had to cast. If it works, you are just lucky to have a platform with uniform addressing scheme.